# Can't find what consume my space "No space left on device"

Tags: 18.04

i am struggling with my ubuntu machine at work, i get
this message when i try to run anything on my CLI or any application (phpstorm, ...)

i have found some similar subject here but couldn't really make any progress. i can't see what is really occupying my space.

Also i don't want to try anything that i'm not understand well, to avoid breaking things.

Please HELP Me.

`fwrite: No space left on device`

```
df -h
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    udev            3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev
    tmpfs           789M  2,0M  787M   1% /run
    /dev/nvme0n1p5   83G   79G  5,9M 100% /
    tmpfs           3,9G   34M  3,9G   1% /dev/shm
    tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
    tmpfs           3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    /dev/nvme0n1p1   96M   31M   66M  32% /boot/efi
    /dev/loop0       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
    /dev/loop2       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/139
    /dev/loop3      1,0M  1,0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/57
    /dev/loop1      3,8M  3,8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
    /dev/loop5      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
    /dev/loop4       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/6531
    /dev/loop7      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/78
    /dev/loop6       35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
    /dev/loop8       91M   91M     0 100% /snap/core/6405
    /dev/loop9      5,9M  5,9M     0 100% /snap/htop/1168
    /dev/loop10      35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1122
    /dev/loop11     261M  261M     0 100% /snap/phpstorm/81
    /dev/loop12     144M  144M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/23
    /dev/loop13     2,3M  2,3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/260
    /dev/loop14      54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/731
    /dev/loop15      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/37
    /dev/loop16     141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/82
    /dev/loop17     3,8M  3,8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
    /dev/loop18      54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/782
    /dev/loop19     264M  264M     0 100% /snap/phpstorm/90
    /dev/loop20      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/206
    /dev/loop22     4,2M  4,2M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/352
    /dev/loop21     3,8M  3,8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/70
    /dev/loop23     5,2M  5,2M     0 100% /snap/htop/1066
    /dev/loop24      36M   36M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
    /dev/loop25      90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6673
    /dev/loop26      13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/103
    /dev/loop27     133M  133M     0 100% /snap/postman/81
    /dev/loop28     261M  261M     0 100% /snap/phpstorm/87
    /dev/loop29     2,4M  2,4M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/180
    /dev/loop30     116M  116M     0 100% /snap/insomnia/24
    tmpfs           789M   16K  789M   1% /run/user/121
    tmpfs           789M   40K  789M   1% /run/user/1000
```

and the command:

```
df -i 
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev           1001835    541 1001294    1% /dev
tmpfs          1009400   1065 1008335    1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5 5521408 805438 4715970   15% /
tmpfs          1009400     80 1009320    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          1009400      5 1009395    1% /run/lock
tmpfs          1009400     18 1009382    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1       0      0       0     - /boot/efi
/dev/loop0        1720   1720       0  100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
/dev/loop2        1598   1598       0  100% /snap/gnome-characters/139
/dev/loop3         354    354       0  100% /snap/gnome-logs/57
/dev/loop1         747    747       0  100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
/dev/loop5       27631  27631       0  100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
/dev/loop4       12815  12815       0  100% /snap/core/6531
/dev/loop7       27631  27631       0  100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/78
/dev/loop6       27345  27345       0  100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
/dev/loop8       12816  12816       0  100% /snap/core/6405
/dev/loop9         785    785       0  100% /snap/htop/1168
/dev/loop10      24092  24092       0  100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1122
/dev/loop11        967    967       0  100% /snap/phpstorm/81
/dev/loop12      27707  27707       0  100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/23
/dev/loop13       1269   1269       0  100% /snap/gnome-calculator/260
/dev/loop14       9856   9856       0  100% /snap/core18/731
/dev/loop15       1720   1720       0  100% /snap/gnome-logs/37
/dev/loop16      27631  27631       0  100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/82
/dev/loop17        724    724       0  100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
/dev/loop18       9862   9862       0  100% /snap/core18/782
/dev/loop19        977    977       0  100% /snap/phpstorm/90
/dev/loop20        271    271       0  100% /snap/gnome-characters/206
/dev/loop22       1549   1549       0  100% /snap/gnome-calculator/352
/dev/loop21        734    734       0  100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/70
/dev/loop23        740    740       0  100% /snap/htop/1066
/dev/loop24      25385  25385       0  100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
/dev/loop25      12819  12819       0  100% /snap/core/6673
/dev/loop26       1597   1597       0  100% /snap/gnome-characters/103
/dev/loop27      37766  37766       0  100% /snap/postman/81
/dev/loop28        967    967       0  100% /snap/phpstorm/87
/dev/loop29       1272   1272       0  100% /snap/gnome-calculator/180
/dev/loop30      10113  10113       0  100% /snap/insomnia/24
tmpfs          1009400     23 1009377    1% /run/user/121
tmpfs          1009400     35 1009365    1% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `du`.

Assuming you have `bash`, you can do:

```
cd /
du -ksh * .* | sort -h;
```

And then keep narrowing it down to the subfolders.

You can also use the GUI utility called `baobab` (as root).

Comment: sudo du -ksh * .* | sort -h;
    du: cannot access 'proc/7219/task/7219/fd/4': No such file or directory
    du: cannot access 'proc/7219/task/7219/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
    du: cannot access 'proc/7219/fd/3': No such file or directory
    du: cannot access 'proc/7219/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
    du: cannot access 'run/user/1000/gvfs': Permission denied
    16K opt
    800K root
    2,1M run
    12M sbin
    13M bin
    14M etc
    17M tmp
    169M boot
    793M lib
    2,5G home
    3,1G usr
    4,1G swapfile
    7,3G snap
    68G var

Comment: i am having problems also with internet now, this is the out put i'm having

Comment: After narrowing it down, it seams that Docker is consuming 60G